# Set Ansible variable to undefined through extra-vars or inventory variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

So I have an Ansible playbook that looks like

```
---
- hosts: mygroup
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

My inventory file looks like

```
[mygroup]
127.0.0.1
```

Since `foo` is not defined anywhere, the debug prints `127.0.0.1` as expected.

But suppose my inventory file looks like

```
[mygroup]
127.0.0.1 foo=null
```

When I run the playbook, it prints out the string `null`. I also tried with `foo=None` and it prints an empty string. How can set the variable to null through inventory or extra-vars?

This may be useful when I want to unset a variable already defined in a playbook.

I am using Ansible version 2.1.1.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python (hence Ansible) differentiates between an undefined variable and a variable with the none value.

There is no way to "undefine" a variable once it has been defined.

In result even if you set the value to `none`, the condition you specified will never consider the variable as undefined.

You get a `""` in the output log because this is how `debug` module displays the none-value, not because it's an empty string.

**Solution 1**

Use a ternary operator with the condition to check for the actual value of `foo` variable:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ((foo is defined) and (foo != None)) | ternary(foo, inventory_hostname) }}"
```

**Solution 2**

Use a "wrapper" dictionary:

1. Define a default value for the variable inside a "wrapper" dictionary:

   ```
   foodict:
     foo: bar
   ```
2. In the play refer the variable as `foodict.foo`:

   ```
   ---
   - hosts: mygroup
     tasks:
       - debug:
           msg: "{{ foodict.foo | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
   ```
3. Override the value in the inventory file by nullifying the "wrapper" dictionary:

   ```
   [mygroup]
   127.0.0.1 foodict=None
   ```