# How to unset a Variable in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

**Is there a possibility to unset a fact (variable) in Ansible?**

Unset in such a way that the check `is defined` fails.

For execution decisions I regularly check conditions with `is defined`. However, it may be necessary to unset these before execution, e.g. if a role is used multiple times via `include_role` or tasks are used multiple times via `include_tasks`.

Is there a special syntax for this, e.g. to use the `set_fact` module?

If I understood it correctly, `meta: clear_facts` takes care of clearing all facts and cannot be restricted to individual ones.

Answer (score 6):

***WARNING: `vars:` on an `include_*` are considered `include params`***

See:

- [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)
- [Modified "vars:" not visible inside include_role](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69799)
- [include params from the list of variable precedence list has no examples](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-documentation/issues/95)

For example, the `vars:` below is not `task vars` (precedence 17.). It is `include params` (precedence 21.). As a result, potential `set_facts` (precedence. 19) inside the role will not override the variable test_var

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: test_role
      vars:
        test_var: first run
```

Use `apply` if you want to provide `task vars` (precedence 17.) to a role

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: test_role
      apply:
        vars:
          test_var: first run
```

This hasn't been documented yet.

---

Q: ***"Is there a possibility to unset a fact (variable) in Ansible?"***

A: No. It is not possible to unset variables in Ansible. Instead, it's possible to define variables in various scopes. Such variables won't be defined above the particular scope. See [*Playbook Keywords*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). You can define variables in this hierarchy of scopes

- Play
- Role
- Block
- Task

There are various scenarios on how to solve the use cases: *`"It may be necessary to unset variables before execution, e.g. if a role is used multiple times via include_role or tasks are used multiple times via include_tasks."`*

For example, create a role

```bash
shell> tree roles/
roles/
└── test_role
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml
```

with the single task

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test_role/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: test_var
```

**Use case 1. A role is used multiple times via include_role**

For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_role:
        name: test_role
      vars:
        test_var: first run

    - include_role:
        name: test_role

    - include_role:
        name: test_role
      vars:
        test_var: third run
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  test_var: first run
  test_var: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
  test_var: third run
```

**Use case 2. Tasks are used multiple times via include_tasks**

In the same way, the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: roles/test_role/tasks/main.yml
      vars:
        test_var: first run

    - include_tasks: roles/test_role/tasks/main.yml

    - include_tasks: roles/test_role/tasks/main.yml
      vars:
        test_var: third run
```

**Use case 3. Use *roles***

The playbook below gives also the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  roles:

    - role: test_role
      test_var: first run

    - role: test_role

    - role: test_role
      test_var: third run
```

---

Notes

- See [Variable Scopes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes)
- It's good to understand what will happen when you declare an empty variable. For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_var: default_value
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
    - set_fact:
        test_var:
    - debug:
        msg: "test_var is defined: {{ test_var is defined }}"
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

shows (abridged) that an empty variable is `defined` and `null`. You  will receive the same results when you set the variable explicitly to *null* by `test_var: !!null`

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: default_value

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'test_var is defined: True'

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: null
```

- It's also good to understand that [*default*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) doesn't set the value when the variable is defined. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: test_var
    - debug:
        var: test_var|default('default when undef')
```

shows that the filter *default* doesn't by default cares the value is *null* and  doesn't set the value because the variable is defined

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: null

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var|default('default when undef'): ''
```

- If you want to set the default value also when the variable is *null* set the second parameter of the filter `True`. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: test_var
    - debug:
        var: test_var|default('default when undef or null', true)
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var: null

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_var|default('default when undef or null', true): default when undef or null
```

Comment: What about `import_role` instead of `include_role`?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your requirement

> *Unset in such a way that the check is defined fails.*

I understand that you like to check for a condition like

```yaml
when: VARIABLE is defined
```

so you could use an approach like

```yaml
when: VARIABLE | default(None) != None
```

and set the value of `VARIABLE` at any time with

```yaml
VARIABLE: !!null
```

**Further Documentation**

- Ansible Issue #[24136](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24136)
- [Set Ansible variable to undefined through extra-vars or inventory variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521998/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to check if a variable is not null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304415/)

**Further Reading**

- Ansible Issue #[75435](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/75435) "*Add an `undef` global Jinja function*"